# Overwriting node dependencies with github forked repo: npm shrinkwrap...?

Tags: node.js, npm, package.json

I am building an app with Angular 4 cli, using the Dragula drag-and-drop stystem [ng2-dragula](https://github.com/bevacqua/dragula). I want to update to [this particular forked repo](https://github.com/nguyenj/dragula) which provides some specific augmentation.

But I am struggling to install this with node. I can't simply run

`npm install git://github.com/nguyenj/dragula.git`

I think because in the `ng2-dragula` package.json, the dependency is specified as

`"dependencies": {
    "dragula": "^3.7.2"
  },`

I have tried to address this using `npm-shrinkwrap`, using the solution posted [here](https://blog.mebooks.co.nz/npm-shrinkwrap-a-great-way-to-hack-dependencies/) (See section *The Real Solution*)

But it isn't working; Even if I manually change the `dependencies` section of the ng2-dragula package.json, running `npm install` just installs the original dragula, NOT the version I want from https://github.com/nguyenj/dragula

Why? How can I solve this?

Answer (score 0):

Actually, this was something quite simple- no need to be overwriting anything- I just needed to specify the branch of the forked repo:

`npm install git://github.com/nguyenj/dragula.git#feature/axis`